# initialising a swift class in an objective c project

Tags: objective-c, swift, init

I'm trying to initialize a Swift class in the main method of my Objective c project.

It works, but it has no class and is nil.

the swift class:

```
import Foundation

@objc class Benotung : NSObject{
    var note: Double
    var matrNr: Int

    init(note:Double, matrNr: Int){
        self.note = note
        self.matrNr = matrNr
    }

    override convenience init(){
        self.init(note: 1.0, matrNr: 1337)
    }

}
```

and the main:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "student.h"
#import <Praktikum-Swift.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Student *hugo = [[Student alloc] init];

        [hugo setAlter: 22 setGroesse: 1.80];
        [hugo setMatrikelNr:12345];

        Benotung *praktikum = [[Benotung alloc]init];
        [praktikum setMatrNr:12345];
        [praktikum setNote:2.0];



            }
    return 0;
}
```

(the student is from another class ;) )